# How can I configure Remote EJB to be accessed via Http in Glassfish

Tags: http, glassfish, ejb, rmi

I am using Remote EJB and I need to access it using Http. I am able to access the remote ejb using usual JNDI lookup. Now I need to access it using Http Url.  How can I configure this?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using JAX-RS?

Comment: Mike, Actually I am working on IIB middleware to integrate remote EJB application. I do not have access to change the implementation of remote application. I tried but could not succeed yet to find solution to map HTTP url to jndi as it can be done for weblogic as explained in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24973/implementing.htm#EJBPG206

Comment: Changing the implementation as Web Service or HTTP tunneling is a way but I am trying to figure out a way that would not require change in implementation of target application or at maximum only deployment configuration change is required.